# non-parametric estimation of E(X) for a symmetric density

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing

I am trying to estimate the expectation of a symmetric density using a kernel density estimation. For a known density, the MLE of this quantity is $\sum_{i=1}^n f ( \theta - X_i)$, for $n$ realisations of $X=(X_1 ... X_n)$. I'm replacing the density by a non-parametric estimate (gaussian kernel, cross-validated bandwidth selection).

I have the following function to get a point estimate of the density in R :

```
density_estimate_gaussian <- function(point,data,bandwidth){

  k_values <- rep(0,length(data))
  for(i in 1:length(data)){
    temp <- (point - data[i])/ bandwidth
    k_values[i] <- dnorm(temp, mean = 0, sd = 1) / bandwidth
  }
  return(sum(k_values) / length(data))
}
```

Using this function, I am computing a point estimate of the log-likelihood with the following function :

```
log_likelihood <- function(theta,data,bandwidth){
  lik_values <- rep(0,length(data))
  for(i in 1:length(data)){
    lik_values[i] <- log(density_estimate_gaussian(theta - 
    data[i],data,bandwidth))  
  }

  return(sum(lik_values))
}
```

Lastly, I am using the `optim` function in R (Brent method) to get my MLE estimation (bandwidth is from a previous KDE with the density(data) R function) :

```
MLE <- optim(par = 2.2,log_likelihood,data = data$V1, bandwidth = 1.67,
             method = "Brent",lower = 1, upper = 3)
```

This is where it gets problematic.

My likelihood is very small in a lot of points, which makes my log-likelihood infinitely small, and I can't get a correct MLE estimate of $E(X)$. An histogram suggests it sits around 2.2.

What am I supposed to do ? Should I remove some extreme data points and optimize my log-likelihood in a smaller region to get a correct estimate ?

My biggest issue would be finding the data points I am supposed to remove. When I compute my log-likelihood in all the grid points used by the density function, the log-likelihood is actually -Inf in most of those. Should I remove the data points closest to the grid point where the log-likelihood is -Inf ?

Are there any obvious errors in my R functions ?

Comment: Why not just use the sample mean?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, that's a school project, and I'm supposed to provide a non-parametric estimation. The sample mean is a good estimator within a parametric model (for example, it's the MLE estimator for the gaussian model), but I cannot simply say it's the sample mean with this non-parametric model

Answer (score 1):

So, your nonparametric model for the density is a mixture of normal distributions:$\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb E}$
$$
\hat P = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \mathcal N(X_i, \sigma^2)
.$$
You're trying to find the best bandwidth $\sigma$ for this model. This is a good thing to do for density estimation.

But, consider the mean of this approximating distribution:
\begin{align}
\E_{Y \sim \hat P}[Y]
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty y \, \mathrm{d}\hat P(y)
\\&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty y \, \left( \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \mathcal N(y; X_i, \sigma^2) \right) \mathrm d y
\\&= \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n  \int_{-\infty}^\infty y \, \mathcal N(y; X_i, \sigma^2) \mathrm d y
\\&= \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n  X_i
,\end{align}
the obvious estimator for the mean in the first place.

So, *no matter the bandwidth*, you're going to get the same estimator for the mean. If you really only care about the mean, then just don't worry about the bandwidth.

Comment: I had not thought of that, thanks a lot, that's a great answer !